# Efficient testing of smoke grenading

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

How to make throwing and testing smoke grenades more efficient? sv_infinite_ammo 1 makes you have many... I'd prefer to throw/place them and shortly see the smoke. Maybe smoke can be made last shorter or be deleted with some command after being set off?

Comment: I don't see how this could be done without modding the server.

Comment: Hm, so there is no duration setting for smoke maybe? I saw a delete entity command some time ago, doesn't that work?

Comment: This is a feature you can request with the developers, but I don't think it's something we can answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use decoy's instead of smokes (they have the exact same fuse/throw arc) and the command "sv_grenade_trajectory 1" to see where they travel. Then once you have the throw down use smokes to see the cover you get and fine tune the throw.

I know its not exactly what you were wanting but its the best way of doing it, that I know at least.

Comment: Nice idea... :)

Answer (score 1):

There are no settings in the base release of Counter Strike Global Offensive that provide the functionality that you're after. I'm not even sure off the top of my head of any mods that would provide you with this functionality.

As pointed out you can use `sv_infinite_ammo 1` which will let you throw as many as you want, but you can't adjust the duration of the smoke bombs or reset the state of a smoke bomb with any in game command or server side setting.

Your only option would likely be using a sourcemod.

Answer (score -2):

you Could bind r_drawparticles so as an Example c "toggle r_drawparticles 0 1"

Comment: a bit late i know :p

Comment: How does this help the asker test smoke grenades?  You should expand your answer with that information.